# Как ускорить код на python - перечисление всех вариантов?

Tags: python

```
import string
out=[]
s=string.ascii_letters
x=0
y=0
z=0
t=0
r=0
f=0
for i in range(len(s)**6):
    out.append(s[x]+s[y]+s[z]+s[t]+s[r]+s[f])
    if x+1==len(s):
        x=-1
        y+=1
    if y==len(s):
        z+=1
    if z==len(s):
        t+=1
    if t==len(s):
        r+=1

    f=f+1 if r==len(s) else f
    r=0 if r==len(s) else r
    t=0 if t==len(s) else t
    z=0 if z==len(s) else z
    y=0 if y==len(s) else y
    x+=1
    
print(len(out))
```

Как можно его ускорить?

Comment: Есть исходный текст задания?

Comment: Это я для себя делаю.

Comment: А что хотели то для себя?

Comment: Ну использовать для подбора всех почт для проверки на существование их

Comment: Вы все 20 миллиардов комбинаций собрались в список запихать? Вы уверены, что у вас есть несколько сотен гигабайт памяти?

Comment: @halwa А как вы будете проверять, что почта существует?

Comment: А вообще, похоже вы пытались реализовать вот это: `import itertools ;    
for a in itertools.product(string.ascii_letters, repeat=6):  
    print(''.join(a[::-1]))`. Если обратный порядок не важен, то можно выкинуть `[::-1]`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Можно применить `itertools` и метод `itertools.product()`. Будете на выходе получать через итератор комбинации. Тогда не придется держать список в памяти.

В примере ниже имеем генератор, который через `product()` в нужном количестве символов строит все варианты сочетаний, потом через `lenght_max_for_fill` проверяем нужно ли нам добирать количество символов до максимальной длины, и, если да, то через переменную `fill` делаем донаполнение строки.

```
import string
import itertools

s = string.ascii_letters


# вариант с итерацией символов до строки нужной длины
def brute(s, count):
    for s in itertools.product(s, repeat=count):
        yield ''.join(s)

a = brute(s, 6)
for _ in range(10):
    print(next(a))

# вариант с добавлением символов из переменной `fill` до нужной длины строки.
def brute(s, count, lenght_max_for_fill = 6, fill = 'a'):
    for s in itertools.product(s, repeat=count):
        yield '{}{}'.format(''.join(s), (lenght_max_for_fill - count) * fill if count < lenght_max_for_fill else '')

a = brute(s, 6, 6, 'a')
for _ in range(10):
    print(next(a))
```

Делать же список длиной в 20 миллиардов элементов память не потянет и времени много уйдет. Даже без дополнительных операций. А Вы еще дополнительно в каждом цикле 9 раз берете длину строки `s`

Comment: можно ли чтобы без создания списка, а сразу перебирать в реальном времени?

Comment: Так оно так и сделано здесь. Переменной `a` присваивается функция-генератор , потом через `next(a)` она каждый раз выдает следующее значение. Вы можете это увидеть на последних трех строчках моего кода. Почитайте https://wiki.python.org/moin/Generators или https://realpython.com/introduction-to-python-generators/ Цикл выдает 10 раз следующее значение.

Answer (score 1):

Несколько раз реализовывал этот алгоритм, но не на питоне а на VB где не было никаких итераторов, генераторов.

Понимаю, что ответ уже дан, но возможно кому-то понравится и этот подход, по сути создается **система счисления** и инкрементация переключает разряды, как по мне - логично и удобно для понимания алгоритма перебора, и условие только одно - на выход из цикла. Можно конечно еще внутренний цикл сделать для краткости, но в данном случае счел лишним, так будет проще для понимания.

Но на скорость не тестировал, скорее всего будет уступать встроенным функциям так как думаю они под это оптимизированы на низком уровне.

```
import string
import time
out=[]
s=string.ascii_letters

def brute_1(count = 10000): 
  n = [0,0,0,0,0,0]
  last = len(n)-1
  m = len(s)
  for i in range(count):
    k = m
    n[5]=i % k  
    n[4]=(i // k) % m
    k *= m
    n[3]=(i // k) % m
    k *= m
    n[2]=(i // k) % m
    k *= m
    n[1]=(i // k) % m
    k *= m
    n[0]=(i // k) % m
    yield(''.join([s[n[0]], s[n[1]],s[n[2]],s[n[3]],s[n[4]],s[n[5]]]))    

# оптимизация на ~42%
def brute_2(count = 10000): 
  m = len(s)
  ka = m
  kb = ka * m
  kc = kb * m
  kd = kc * m
  ke = kd * m
  kf = ke * m
  out = 0
  for i in range(count):
    a=i % m
    b=(i // kb) % m
    c=(i // kc) % m
    d=(i // kd) % m
    e=(i // ke) % m
    f=(i // kf) % m
    yield(f'{s[f]}{s[e]}{s[d]}{s[c]}{s[b]}{s[a]}')  

start = time.time()
a = brute_1(7311616)
for _ in range(7311616):
  next(a) 
print((time.time() - start)*1000.0)  # 14443.275

start = time.time()
a = brute_2(7311616)
for _ in range(7311616):
  next(a) 
print((time.time() - start)*1000.0)  # 8506.388
```

Comment: Разница с моим вариантом примерно в два раза по времени, но реализация хорошая, когда ничего кроме нет.

Comment: @AndyPavlov спасибо за результаты тестирования, ну а так да это как раз тот случай когда нет возможности реализовать иначе.

Comment: Кстати замерил для трех элементов оба варианта без вывода, по времени практически тоже самое плюс, минус, немного странно.

Comment: @AndyPavlov хотел проверить на 4 элемента, Ваш код сломался в чем может быть дело? Я просто подставил 7311616 в цикл, нужны ли еще какие-то настройки?

Comment: Я обернул Ваш код в виде функции-итератора и прогнал по своей тест системе, а также на обычном timeit. Можете кинуть свой код куда-то? Я варианты от 1 до 6 символов прогонял для оценки времени, все работало

Comment: Скинул пример в https://gist.github.com/ndrwpvlv/3d08e76f7a9dbd51daf2a06936a7ec3a с обычным замером по `time()`. Он у меня плюс-минус похожий вариант дает с другими вариантами тестирования по отношению времени по вашей функции и моей.

Comment: Посмотрел код там тоже ломается, можете сами подставить `for _ in range(7311616):` и убедится я хотел бы понять почему ваш вариант падает и возможно ли переписать его так чтобы он не падал, возможно я что-то еще упускаю и только range не дотаточно

Comment: Там пример для `xyzaaa`, где `xyz` меняет итеративно, а `aaa` подставляется. Строим 6 символов итеративно и все работает `a = brute(s, 6, 6, 'a')` или оно же `a = brute(s, 6)`. В принципе оно не нужно там, а сделано для примера.

Comment: Да так заработало

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/128035/discussion-between-andy-pavlov-and-daniil-loban).